# Оператор delete может вернуть false при use strict?

Tags: javascript

Читаю книжку по javascript (Флэнеган), конкретно сейчас - про оператор delete.

> Оператор
>   delete не удаляет
>   ненастраиваемые
>   свойства,
>   атрибут
>   configurable которых
>   имеет
>   значение
>   false. (Однако
>   он может
>   удалять
>   настраиваемые
>   свойства
>   нерасширяемых
>   объектов.)
>   Ненастраиваемыми
>   являются
>   свойства
>   встроенных
>   объектов,
>   а также
>   свойства
>   глобального
>   объекта,
>   созданные
>   с помощью
>   инструкций
>   объявления
>   переменных
>   и функций.
>   Попытка
>   удалить
>   ненастраиваемое
>   свойство
>   в строгом
>   режиме
>   вызывает
>   исключение
>   TypeError. В нестрогом
>   режиме
>   (и в реализациях
>   ECMAScript
>   3) в таких
>   случаях
>   оператор
>   delete просто
>   возвращает
>   false

Провела парочку тестов в консоли, чтобы убедиться, что все именно так и работает. Возникает вопрос: а есть вообще какой-то случай, при котором delete при use strict вернет false, а не кинет исключение?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, если посмотреть [спецификацию](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf), а именно пункт 12.5.3.2 Runtime Semantics: Evaluation, то мы увидим:

> When a delete operator occurs within strict mode code, a SyntaxError
>   exception is thrown if its UnaryExpression is a direct reference to a
>   variable, function argument, or function name. In addition, if adelete
>   operator occurs within strict mode code and the property to be deleted
>   has the attribute {[[Configurable]]: false }, a TypeError exception
>   is thrown.

Так что, не должно быть такого. Разве что, в каких-то кривых браузерах, которые не смогли нормально реализовать спеку.